# merge autocomplete results from multiple sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently getting autocomplete results from a single source. If I wanted to also get results from a second source how would I go about this, and can I add the results on the fly (if one of the sources took longer).

For example this is a form field which is autocompleted using town names from geonames.org.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6YFx/

How would I impliment merging the results from a second source such as Google Geocode API:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': request.term, 'region': 'GB' }, function(results, status) {
    response($.map(results, function(item) {
        return {
            value: item.formatted_address+' (google)',
            latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
            longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
        }
    }));
})
```

The google results are quicker to fetch, so I'd like to show these when they are ready and then when I get the geonames.org results I'd like to add these to the mix.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it in the end http://jsfiddle.net/ekzMN/89/

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you came up with.  But I don't see any call out to Google in the Javascript?

Comment: The shared link doesn't work anymore! Can you share another link.

Answer (score 0):

Try adapting the code from this SO post:

[jQuery UI autocomplete - multiple sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018615/jquery-ui-autocomplete-multiple-sources/4018733#4018733)