# Jquery UI Autocomplete to search through multiple XML elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a JQuery UI autocomplete widget that is currently looking at a database of contacts. Users can search by contact name, email, company etc. However the query is a little complex and can lag occasionally, so I am looking to switch it to a dynamically XML file for speed, yet I want to keep to ability to search on multiple fields. I cant not figure out how to do this currently, could anyone point me in the right direction of how to match the term to multiple XML fields? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

This question of 2010 looks similar:
[Jquery ui autocomplete - multiple sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018615/jquery-ui-autocomplete-multiple-sources)
I would suggest combining the first answer with the second answer. As far as I remember when I was working with the JQuery autocomplete I found it required JavaScript Object Notation in order to function, not XML.

Hope this helps :)